# How to explore which classes are loaded from which JARs?

Tags: java, profiling, classloader, jar

Is there a way to determine which classes are loaded from which JARs at runtime?

I'm sure we've all been in JAR hell before. I've run across this problem a lot troubleshooting `ClassNotFoundException`s and `NoClassDefFoundError`s on projects.  I'd like to avoid finding all instances of a class in JARs and using process of elimination on the code causing a CNFE to find the culprit.

Will any profiling or management tools give you this kind of information?

This problem is super annoying purely because we should have this information at the time the class gets loaded.  There has to be a way to get to it, or record it and find it, yet I know of nothing that will do this, do you?

I know OSGi and versioned bundles/modules aim to make this a non issue... but it doesn't seem to be going away any time soon.

Note: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139534/classloader-issues-how-to-determine-which-library-versions-jar-files-are-load) is a subset of my question related to classes loaded from versioned jars.

Somewhat related, this post explains a strategy to search for a class within JARs (either under the current directory) or in your M2_REPO:  [JarScan, scan all JAR files in all subfolders for specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759923/jarscan-scan-all-jar-files-in-all-subfolders-for-specific-class)

Also somewhat related, [JBoss Tattletale](http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/developerguide/en/html_single/)

Comment: Jason Day has it right, this basically a duplicate of a question I asked not so long ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779650/where-on-the-file-system-was-my-java-class-loaded-from

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Passing the `-verbose:class` switch to the `java` command will print each class loaded and where it was loaded from.

[Joops](http://code.google.com/p/joops/) is also a nice tool for finding missing classes ahead of time.

Comment: Nice - Joops looks cool - do you know if it is smart enough to follow a class referenced through Class.forName?

Comment: I would be surprised if it could follow Class.forName references, but I don't know for sure. Joops also has a `which` command, so you could use that to manually check for classes by name.

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton! Helped me figure out conflicting class loading!

Comment: How about already running JVM which I don't have control over? i.e. I can't restart it with -verbose:class option. may not be possible since jvm never keeps log of it without -verbose:class option but just wondering.

Answer (score 15):

From code you can call:

```
myObject.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
```

(Note, `getProtectionDomain` may unfortunately return `null` (bad design), so "proper code" would check for that.)

Comment: This wouldn't help with a CNFE or NCDFE; when have you done this?

Comment: Presumably if you get a ClassNotFoundException then you presumably already know the class is not in any of the jars. (Assuming you are not playing with class loaders.) There may be issues if there are other errors during class loading, like a missing superclass.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline you can get `ClassNotFoundException` if a static initializer of the said class throws an exception. Then you have the class in the jar file, but the ClassLoader can not load it.

Comment: This can be used in an Eclipse debugging Expression if you don't want to (or can't) modify the code.

Answer (score 4):

There is an MBean for the JVM flag mentioned by Jason Day above.

If you are using JBoss, you can twiddle this on demand using JMX, if you add the native JMX MBean server to your config.  Add the following -D's:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver 
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl
-DJBOSS_CLASSPATH="../lib/jboss-system-jmx.jar"
```

And then you can see this setting under the java.lang:Classloading MBean and can cut it on/off on the fly.  This is helpful if you only want it on while executing a certain piece of code.

There is also an MBean which will allow you to enter a fully qualified classname and see where it was loaded from in the class hierarchy.  The MBean is called LoaderRepository and you'll want to invoke the displayClassInfo() operation, passing in the FQCN.

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere (WAS) you can use a feature called "Class Loader Viewer"

Enable the class loader viewer first by clicking Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Class loader viewer service, enable the service and restart the server.

Then you can go to Troubleshooting > Class Loader Viewer and searching for your class or package name.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can easily export a JMX operation to access package info for any loaded class in you process like:

```
  public static final class Jmx {

    @JmxExport
    public static Reflections.PackageInfo getPackageInfo(@JmxExport("className") final String className) {
      return Reflections.getPackageInfo(className);
    }
  }
```

and here is a simple unit test to export and invoke it:

```
  @Test
  public void testClassLocator() throws IOException, InstanceNotFoundException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {
    Registry.export(Jmx.class);
    Reflections.PackageInfo info = (Reflections.PackageInfo) Client.callOperation(
            "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi",
            Jmx.class.getPackage().getName(),
            Jmx.class.getSimpleName(), "getPackageInfo", Registry.class.getName());
    System.out.println(info);
    Assert.assertNotNull(info);
  }
```

this is all based using some small utilities library from spf4j (http://www.spf4j.org)

you can see this code [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/base/Runtime.java#L669) and the test [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/test/java/org/spf4j/jmx/RegistryTest.java#L263)