# Directory list of JAR file within classpath

Tags: java, jar, classloader

The typically method to reference a file contained with a JAR file is to use `ClassLoader.getResource`. Is there a way to get the contents of a directory within a JAR files (similar to `java.io.File.listFiles()`)? Note that the JAR file is within the classpath and its filename might not be known during runtime.

Basically I have a bunch of non-.class resource files within a directory. At runtime I need to load each resource file contained within a known directory.

Comment: See ["List files inside a JAR"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/list-files-inside-a-jar/1429275#1429275).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

There is a system property called java.class.path, parse the path to your jar and then use [JarURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) class to do what you want.