# Check if any Zip file is present on a given path

Tags: java, regex, zip

I want to check whether any Zip file is present on a specified path.  If present then I want to extract that file on the same path.

How to check if any Zip file is present on a given path?

Comment: Try to open the zip file in Try-Catch block, it open successfully then it is exists, else , it will go in to catch block :)

Comment: Check out this question, you can apply it to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/

Comment: BTW - DYM 1 specific archive, or all archives in all directories under a given path, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code which checks the extension of the file inside the directory and prints the filename if Zip file is present.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  // Directory path here
  String path = "."; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
       if (files.endsWith(".rar") || files.endsWith(".zip"))
       {
          System.out.println(files);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Instead of that If you want to use `FilenameFilter` as told by Andrew Thompson.

You can implement FilenameFilter  in your class.
More help is given on this [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=384).
By this you dont need to check the extension of file .
It will give you only those files which extension is being passed as a parameter.

To extract the zip file if found you can take help of the `ZipInputStream`  package .
You can have a look [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.zip/how-to-extract-file-files-from-a-zip-file-3.html) to extract the folder.

Comment: `folder.listFiles()` This where [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) come in handy.

Comment: @vikiiii I think Andrew's point was that, rather than returning a complete list of files in the directory and then iterating through them, you should pass a `FilenameFilter` that checks for the `.zip` extension, thereby only returning the files you care about.

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if Any Zip file is present on a given path?

See [`File.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: vikiii is correct i want to check whether the zip file is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

This unzips all files in a directory, but it's easy to modify to only unzip a specific file.

```
package com.wedgeless.stackoverflow;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

/**
 * Unzips all zip files in a directory
 * @author mk
 */
public final class Unzipper
{
  public static final String DOT_ZIP = ".ZIP";
  public static final FilenameFilter DOT_ZIP_FILTER = new FilenameFilter()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
      return name.toUpperCase().endsWith(DOT_ZIP);
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    File dir = new File("/path/to/dir");
    Unzipper unzipper = new Unzipper();
    unzipper.unzipDir(dir);
  }

  public void unzipDir(File dir)
  {
    for (File file : dir.listFiles(DOT_ZIP_FILTER))
    {
      unzip(file);
    }
  }

  protected void unzip(File file)
  {
    File dir = getZipDir(file);
    try
    {
      dir.mkdirs();
      ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
      Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zip.entries();
      while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements())
      {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipEntries.nextElement();
        File outputFile = new File(dir, zipEntry.getName());
        outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        if (!zipEntry.isDirectory())
        {
          write(zip, zipEntry, outputFile);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      dir.delete();
    }
  }

  protected void write(ZipFile zip, ZipEntry zipEntry, File outputFile)
    throws IOException
  {
    final BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(zipEntry));
    final int buffsize = 1024;
    final byte buffer[] = new byte[buffsize];
    final BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), buffsize);
    try
    {
      while (input.available() > 0)
      {
        input.read(buffer, 0, buffsize);
        output.write(buffer, 0, buffsize);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      output.flush();
      output.close();
      input.close();
    }
  }

  protected File getZipDir(File zip)
  {
    File dir = zip.getParentFile();

    int index = zip.getName().toUpperCase().lastIndexOf(DOT_ZIP);
    String zipPath = zip.getName().substring(0, index);
    File zipDir = new File(dir, zipPath);
    return zipDir;
  }
}
```

It's also not puzzled when on those rare occasions you get zip files with a extension in a non-standard case e.g. `file.ZIP`

**edit:** I guess I should have read the question more carefully. You only asked how to identify if a zip file existed on a path, not how to extract it. Just use the FilenameFilter approach... if you get any hits return true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

Take a File variable and go through all the files inside the director and ckeck for a .zip or .tar.gz or .rar
[How to iterate over the files of a certain directory, in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917326/how-to-iterate-over-the-files-of-a-certain-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test the availability of *any* resource that you want to use is just to *try to use it.* Any other technique is vulnerable to timing-window problems, critique that you are trying to predict the future, double coding, etc. etc. etc. Just catch the `FileNotFoundException` that happens when you try to open it. You have to catch it anyway, why write the same code twice?