# call files by directory not by name in java

Tags: java, excel

I have an application that is converting a type of files.
while working on the project, i've been testing files by calling them by name, but i want to dynamise that call.

Example 1:
`String oldFileName = "2015.xls";`

Example 2
`Reader reader = new FileReader("2015.xls");`

Comment: Unclear. Do you mean something like `Reader reader = new FileReader(oldFileName);`?

Comment: no the two lines are not directly related .. i just give examples of how i am calling files along the project

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917326/how-to-iterate-over-the-files-of-a-certain-directory-in-java) can point you the right way.