# Indexing file names in java

Tags: java

I am trying to index multiple file names (.txt) in an array.

for example

`static String[] filename = new String[40];`

and I have 40 files in the project directory. I want to insert their names into an array using a for loop rather than typing it manually. `filename[0] = ".txt"`.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't find a solution **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)**?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly... can't you simply use [java.io.listFiles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)?

Comment: @Till Helge Helwiq: I tried it an it is giving me an error on showFiles(files). I have entered the project directory path where the files are located. Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I would look at creating a File object (to the directory containing the files you want to list), then invoking listFiles()-method iterating over the files and populating your String array from that.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`FileFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html)
- Use [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [`FilenameFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) that accepts files with names ending `.txt`.

Pass that filter to [`theFile.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) to get a nice `File[]` that will contain the text files located in the directory represented by `theFile`.

And forget:

1. Keeping a `String[]` of names that represent `File[]`.  If a `File` is needed, keep an array of `File`.
2. Using an expandable list (`ArrayList`, `Vector`) - it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File(dirname);

String[] filenames = dir.list();
```

**Edit:** 
Sample program that lists the files in the current directory:

```
import java.io.*;

class dir {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    File dir = new File(".");
    String[] filenames = dir.list();

    for (int i= 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(filenames[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is showing null when I try to print the string. Rather than dirname I have entered the path for the files ??

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    filename[i] = ".txt";
}
```

Beside the fact that `String[]` is not really the best solution for that.. What about using an ArrayList? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html