# Dir recursion - what happens if first file encounters is a dir

Tags: java, file-io, recursion

What happens if the first file this code encounters is a dir. Why does it not ignore all other files in that dir (therefore obscuring the results)?

This is taken from [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

I'm not trying to dispute that this code works but how does it account for above scenario ?

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
        File[] files = new File("C:/").listFiles();
        showFiles(files);
    }

    public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
            } else {
                System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't ignore it because it's just making another recursive call - the original call (with the collection of files from the top level) is still on the stack. It makes a *new* call with a *new* list of files, referenced by a *new* parameter called `files` in a *new* stack frame.

So if there's a directory structure of `c:/a/b/c` you'll end up with a stack of:

```
showFiles([c:/a/b/c])
showFiles([c:/a/b])
showFiles([c:/a])
main(...)
```

When the "deepest" call (the top of the stack) returns, the next stack frame will still know about any *other* files at the same level, and may well recurse again.

Answer (score 2):

When the first entry it encounters is a directory, it **recursively** calls `showFiles()` to work through the contents of that directory. When this call returns, the loop continues on with the entries from the first call to `showFiles()`.

Answer (score 1):

It just pushes another stack frame, when the recursive call finishes, it can resume where it previously left.

Answer (score 0):

It works because the variable `files` is a local variable, i.e. there is one instance for each invocation of the method `showFiles`. This way all method executions are independent from one another and do not clobber their `files` variables.