# How to get all the media files on a computer

Tags: java, file, java-io

Is there a built in way to get all of the media files (movies , music)  on a computer in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not build in. But, you could create a crawler that scans your entire hard drive for files with certain extensions ( or even better, MIME types ).

Check out this answer for an easy way to iterate through directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154523/691606

See also [Get the Mime Type from a File](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html). Based on 1st 2 (of 3) techniques shown therein, is this:

```
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import java.io.File;

class MimeForMedia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] types = {
            "png", "jpg", "gif", "tif", "bmp",  // image
            "snd", "wav", "mp3", "ogg", "au",   // sound
            "mov", "avi", "mpg", "flv"  // video
            };
        MimetypesFileTypeMap typeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
        for (String type : types) {
            String name = "a." + type;
            String bestType = typeMap.getContentType(name);
            if (bestType.equals("application/octet-stream")) {
                System.out.print( "Using URLConnection:  " );
                try {
                    bestType = (new File(name)).toURI().toURL()
                        .openConnection().getContentType();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                }
            }
            System.out.println (type + "  " + bestType);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results on a Windows 7 PC.

```
Using URLConnection:  png  image/png
jpg  image/jpeg
gif  image/gif
tif  image/tiff
Using URLConnection:  bmp  content/unknown
Using URLConnection:  snd  audio/basic
wav  audio/x-wav
Using URLConnection:  mp3  content/unknown
Using URLConnection:  ogg  content/unknown
au  audio/basic
mov  video/quicktime
avi  video/x-msvideo
mpg  video/mpeg
Using URLConnection:  flv  content/unknown
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: *"( or even better, MIME types )."*  Good idea, bu what J2SE class provides the MIME/content type?  I could not see anything in `File` or `FileSystemView` that covered it.

Comment: You most likely need an external library.
Check http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html for some examples.

Comment: I added some code/ouptut that I found surprising in the following respects. 1) PNG was not in the map.  2) TIFF was. 3) BMP was not recognized in either the map or via `URLConnection`. 4) MP3 was not recognized by either. Huh.

Comment: wow thanks a lot. this should be a lot better than the method i did by looking at extensions!

Comment: I would call this class "IndexForMedia".

Answer (score 5):

Iterate on all the folders of your file system and look for files with the extensions you need (if you have time).