# File format to store multiple type data in single archieve

Tags: java, compression

I have one requirement , Like I want to store data(text,images,video,audio etc.) in one single compressed file using java.
Idea of this is that every thing is stored in structured format so that later I can refer to some metadata file in compressed file and retrieve data accordingly.
So is there any open java library available on internet.Please do guide.Thanks

Comment: Does `java.util.zip` count?

Comment: Actually I can use zip but it just compresses , I need to store data in structured format , I need to retrieve data at run time , lets say I want image only so I will fetch image only leaving others intact.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by storing data in a structured format.  Using java.util.zip.ZipFile, you should be able to iterate files in the ZIP archive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004811/iterating-over-all-directories-in-a-zip-file-java

Answer (score 0):

[How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-io/973-how-work-zip-files-java.html