# Pass all files inside a folder as an input to a function

Tags: java, methods, input

How to pass all files inside a folder as an input to a function?

lets say I have an folder called A and inside this folder I have three files as `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`.

On the other hand I have a function which gets a file name as input. How can I say run this function with all of the files inside folder A as your input.

if the function is

```
void readfile(String x)
```

I want to call `readfile("1.txt")`, `readfile("2.txt")` and `readfile("3.txt")`.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Loop over the files in the directory. See ["\[java\] list directory"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+list+directory) for many related questions/examples like ["Best way to iterate through a directory in java?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the files from a directory as follows

```
File mainFolder = new File("C:\\yourDir");
getFiles(mainFolder);

public void getFiles(File f)
{
   File files[];
   if(f.isFile())
   System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
   else
   {
      files = f.listFiles();
      for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
      {
         getFiles(files[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

This code just prints the files. You can store it a `Set<String>` and then give it to your function. To read from different files you will need to create that many FileReaders.
For example

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file1.txt")));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file2.txt")));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file3.txt")));
```

If you wish to each line from all 3 files at a time I suugest you create an infinite for loop and check `if(reader1.readLine()!=null)` for each reader. You can `break;` when all all readers **return null**. Do not forget to close the streams in **finally block**.

```
reader1.close();
reader1.close();
reader1.close();
```