# How to send a directory of files

Tags: java, inputstream

I need to change this code so that it will send a directory of image files at the moment it currently only sends one file, my main goal is to have it ask for a directory and then send all of the files in that directory (image files) to the server i then need it to display how much data was sent the code i currently have is:

Client:

```
package sockets;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int filesize=1022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",6789);
        byte [] bytearray  = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("copy.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        currentTot = bytesRead;
        System.out.println("The Size of the data transferred is " + bytesRead + " Bytes");

        do {
           bytesRead =
              is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
           if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
        } while(bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        socket.close();
      }
}
```

Server:

```
package sockets;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Server {


 public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {`

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
              Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
              System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
              File transferFile = new File ("Orders.txt");
              byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()];
              FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
              BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
              bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
              OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
              System.out.println("Sending Files...");
              os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
              os.flush();
              socket.close();
              System.out.println("File transfer complete");
            }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all files in the selected directory and get all the known image extensions you want to send.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java) for iterating over files.

Then, stream the bytes in each of those files from your client to your server.

I suggest using [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) for sending your files to your server as its an established protocol for precisely this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to send the directory completely, as is. You have 2 options:

1. Create a zip file, and send that.
2. Open the directory and iterate over the entire directory and send each file individually.

Comment: If i took the second option could you show an example piece of code on how i would have it iterate the directory thanks