# Search a string in entire workspace using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to write a program in java to search a string in entire workspace using eclipse search plugin in my code.
I have searched for this problem but couldnt find the result.
Kindly help.
Every suggestion is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have tried?If new to the eclipse plugin development then search for tutorials in google

Comment: I tried to search for a string in 1 file using simple java search code. Now I want to search that string in entire workspace. Forget about the plugin part. How should I search for a string in entire workspace? Can any1 provide me code for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to present the results in the Eclipse `Search` view (like the existing `Search > File Search`) or just do the search in your own code.

Comment: I want to do search in my own code @greg-449.

Comment: Use apache lucene file search. search for tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that there already is such a functionality in Eclipse, do you? In Eclipse `Search` -> `File...` enter your text, select `*.*` as the *File name patterns*, and `workspace` as *Scope*.

Or do you maybe want to write a plugin that uses this search internally?

From your comments I get the picture that you are looking for code to loop through directories/files and search through them. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java) can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following to recurse through all the projects and folders for file:

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;


// Get all the projects in the workspace

IProject [] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();

// Search each project

for (IProject project : projects)
 {
   searchContainer(project);
 }


/*
 * Search a project or folder.
 */
private void searchContainer(IContainer container)
{
   // Get all the resources in the container

   IResource [] members = container.members();

   // Look at each resource

   for (IResource member : members)
     {
        if (member instanceof IContainer)
         {
           // Resource is a folder, search that

           searchContainer((IContainer)member);
         }
        else if (member instanceof IFile)
         {
           // Resource is a file, search that
           searchFile((IFile)member);
         }
     }
}

/*
 * Search a file.
 */
private void searchFile(IFile file)
{
  // TODO search the file
}
```

You should run this in a `Job` or other background task as it may take some time to run.

Comment: @SebastianH I went through your suggested question n I tried compiling both the code bt was unable to get results. Thanks for your help but can suggest another solution.

Comment: I am not able to umderstand your code can u explain it by adding comments in it @Greg-449. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Greg-449 for comments but I am confused as what should I declare icontainer,iresource etc if possible can u reveal entire code with explanation it will really grateful of you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting many classloader error. Don't know why. Greg-449 can u help me getting put of this problem I am stuck in this for 2-3 days. If possible provide code for search string. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your plug-in manifest.mf. You are using `Run > Eclipse Application` to run the plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using run >Eclipse application.

Comment: Guys i have tried doing this program to search string. I didn't got expected results as this program search string among files(eg txt,java) but it doesn't search among subfolders. kindly help.

Comment: i have posted my code as answer. kindly comment on it and give your suggestion. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

package search_workspace09;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class workspace_search09
{

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        String dirName="D:/test_folder";
        String stringsearch="world";   
        //String fileName = "test.txt";

        File dir = new File(dirName);

        // Open the file c:\test.txt as a buffered reader

        File[] dirs=dir.listFiles();
         if(dirs!=null)
         {
        for (int i=0;i<dirs.length;i++)
        {      
            if(dirs[i].isFile())
            {
            File filename=dirs[i];
            System.out.println("Files to search in " +filename);
            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));         
            //System.out.println(filename);

            // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current line.
            int countline=0;
            String line;        

            //pattern search
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+stringsearch+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            System.out.println("Search Criteria " +" Filename\t\t\t"+ " Line no. " + " Position\t" + " Line Text ");

            while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Increment the count and find the index of the word
                countline++;

                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                // indicate all matches on the line

                while(m.find())
                {                   
                    System.out.println(stringsearch +"\t\t"+ filename+"\t\t" + countline + "\t " + m.start() + "\t"+line);                   
                }                    
            }
            //continue;
        }          
    }}}
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class workspace_search14
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{      
    String dir="D:/test_folder";
    File root=new File(dir);
    findFiles(root,0);       
}   
public static void findFiles(File root,int depth) throws IOException
{
    File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        String iName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
        {
            if (iName.endsWith(".txt") || iName.endsWith(".TXT")||iName.endsWith(".java"))
            {  
                for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
                    System.out.print("\t");
                System.out.println("\nFile_Name: "+iName);
                searchFiles(listOfFiles[i]);                                   
              }
        }
        else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
        {  
            for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
                System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.println("\nDirectory_Name: "+iName);
            findFiles(listOfFiles[i], depth+1);               
        }
    }
}    
public static void searchFiles(File FileName)throws IOException
{         
    int countline=0;
    String line;        
    String stringsearch="world";  
    BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+stringsearch+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    System.out.println("Search Criteria " +" Filename\t\t\t"+ " Line no. " + " Position\t" + " Line Text ");

    while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        countline++;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        while(m.find())
        {                   
            System.out.println(stringsearch +"\t\t"+ FileName+"\t\t" + countline + "\t " + m.start() + "\t"+line);                   
        }}}}
```

Comment: This code works for searching a string in entire workspace. It displays filename,line no.,position,line text. I would like to thank everyone for helping and giving their suggestion.