# How to create an InputStream of files that have a certain extension in Java?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a lot of files in a directory but I only want to read the ones with a certain extension (say .txt). I want these files added to the same BufferedInputStream so that I can read them in one go. When I call read() at the end of a file, the next one should begin.

It really feels like there should be an obvious answer to this but I had no luck finding it.

Comment: "It really feels like there should be an obvious answer to this" - why? Do you think this a particularly common requirement?

Comment: And how large are these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [SequenceInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html):

> A SequenceInputStream represents the logical concatenation of other
>   input streams. It starts out with an ordered collection of input
>   streams and reads from the first one until end of file is reached,
>   whereupon it reads from the second one, and so on, until end of file
>   is reached on the last of the contained input streams.

Answer (score 1):

To me the "obvious answer" is:

Just [iterate through all the files in the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java) using a proper filter. For each file create a [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), read it and close it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an obvious answer to this question.

Probably you need to create a Wrapper InputStream with a list of files you want to read from. Internally you will open/close streams as needed, namely when a file is completely read.

It is not obvious but should not be difficult. This way you can work 'only' with one InputStream for all files.