# How to print the directory tree from the list of strings?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a library that could help me to print the directory tree from the list of strings.

List

```
  "/a/b/c/file1.txt"
  "/a/b/c/file2.txt"
  "/a/b/file3.jpg"
  and so on...
```

Comment: The answer to your question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

Comment: It is not exactly my case. Because I want to print an abstract file tree. It doesn't exist on my file system.

Comment: So, in what data structure does your 'abstract file tree' exist?

Comment: In List<String> where list element is a path: `a/b/c/file.txt`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you please re-explain your problem and the things you tried?

Comment: Tried to get it done in a day, but it takes some more time, give me another hour or 5

Comment: @Charlie Or another year (I'm trying to say you need to give errors, not questions. Try something on your own, and if you're having struggle with a certain part, ask that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try abego tree layout.  It gives you a way to display trees. It doesn't appear to be well documented but it works well.  Here is a link to how to use it. https://code.google.com/p/treelayout/