# Signing a folder using digital signature in java

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I am trying to sign a folder using digital signature.I am able to sign  a file.But Now i need to sign  a folder containing multiple files.Please help me with an example that will suffice my requirement

Comment: *trying to sign a folder* - what do you mean? Sign each file in that folder or create a single signature for the whole folder (probably wrapped in some container archive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this way to iterate on folder here: [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java]), but except of calling `System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());` for each file call you signing method.
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Javadocs for security and digital sign generation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html