# File iteration over directory with variable input files in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and need help as in How I should go ahead? I wrote a Java Program, which takes

```
FileInputStream(t$i.txt) //input to Java Program
```

and produces

```
FileOutputStream(model$i.txt) //Output of Java Program
```

$i runs from 0 to 100. There is a directory which contains files and shall be iterated in FileInputstream as below.

```
t0.txt
t1.txt
t2.txt
t3.txt
...
...
...
t100.txt
```

And produce corresponding FileoutputStream as below.

```
model0.txt
model1.txt
model2.txt
model3.txt
.
.
.
model100.txt
```

Reference: [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Still, where do you get stuck? You do know how to write a loop and concatenate strings to produce the file names, or is that a problem?

Comment: @Bram I am facing problem in concatenating the strings and calling the input file names and at the same time producing the output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        File in = new File("t" + i + ".txt");
        if (in.exists()) {
            try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(in);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("model" + i + ".txt")) {
                // write something on fos depending on fis;
            }
        }
    }
```

where the try-with-resources construction takes care of closing the streams.