# Iterate through multiple image files

Tags: java, image, loops

Is it possible to iterate through multiple image files?  For example, given the following code, iterate through "someImage.jpg" to someImage20.jpg"? I still want the code following the BufferedImage to execute for each image of course.

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("someImage.jpg"));
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            ch[red / 128][green / 128][blue / 128]++;
```

Comment: Please include the language you want to work in in the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through files in an outer loop. See instructions here: [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java) and process each File with your code block.