# Serving list of files via a spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. my js files and other static files are under /static and when i type something like "http://application ip:port/file1.txt and file1.txt" is under /static, i am able to see it.

But i want to create a directotry say "/static/mydownloads" and want the list of files to be displayed that user can download say
"http://application ip:port/static/mydownloads" must display list of files i can download
"file1d.txt`
file2d.txt
file3d.txt"
and person can download it by clicking on it. I tried resolvers and other random things but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want something like most HTTP daemons have, a directory listing. Well, if you want something like that in Spring Boot, you'll have to develop it by yourself.

First of all, you need a controller. You'll have to loop over all files in a specific directory manually, probably using `java.io.File`. More information about that can be found in this answer: 
[How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java)

Then you'll have to convert the file listing to a model, and use Spring MVC to display a listing of those files.

Comment: thanks. so it seems like there is no default straightforward way to do it. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: @virtualgod Indeed, Spring Boot is just Spring, it's a framework for web applications, not a webserver for static file serving. If you want such a feature, you'll still have to write it yourself, but honestly, I don't think it's that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot lists /static as a resource folder automatically so it will have to override or extend that functionality to have /static be handled by multiple controllers. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

The easiest is probably to hook up a different controller for /mydownloads instead and let it list all the static resources available in /static/mydownloads.

Comment: ok i am willing to add a different controller but i am still not clear how will i do that and if that will list all files in a particular directory. can you share any more clues. I will very much appreciate it

Comment: i tried the resource handler stuff by adding my own path but it is not working. i can share the snippet if that helps