# scan series of folders in JAVA

Tags: java, linux

I have series of folders, inside which there are files to be processed.Inside each folder, there are maybe other sub-folders as well, which are to be scanned. 
I wish to know if there is any way to do that. Whatever open-source code I could find, they were all for scanning only 1 folder.

The directory structure (rough sketch) in my case is as follows:
[image]

So far, I just got this:

```
public static void directory(File dir){
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for(File file:files){
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    if(file.listFiles() != null)
        directory(file);        
}}
```

Please Help !

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: "*I wish to know if there is any way to do that*" yes is a way. Try recursion like `scan(File f){ for each element in directory (if element is directory){scan(element)} else {handle(element)}}`.

Comment: the above link is for listing files in a single directory.. I have multiple directories, and that's where I am stuck..

Comment: @Mureinik right now, I am only able to scan only one directory, I cannot go inside the sub-directories.

Comment: since Java 7 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3154643/1393766, since Java 8 http://stackoverflow.com/a/24006711/1393766

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this.

```
public void listfiles(String directoryURL, List<File> fileList) {
    File directory = new File(directoryURL);
    File[] fileArray = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fileArray) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), fileList);
        }
    }
}
```