# How to change permission of files recursively with terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, file, terminal, permissions

I would know how to change permission of all java files in a folder and in each his subfolder recursively. Thank you

Comment: If you mean "what is the unix command", that is off-topic here.  SO is for programming questions, not general computer questions.  There's a superuser exchange for that sort of thing.

Comment: If you're asking about how to write a Java program to do this, see [How do I iterate through files in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java) and [How do I programmatically change file permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Comment: java / terminal: seems to be inconsistency here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then use: `find` to search corresponding files and then change mode for each:

```
find <dir> -name "*.java" -exec chmod <access> {} \;
```