# OpenCV read multiple images from a directory (java)

Tags: java, opencv, highgui

I'm trying to read multiple images from a file using OpenCV. The current code I have can only read one image at a time

```
Mat source = Highgui.imread(filename,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

I'd like to load the images into an array and then read them using OpenCV. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I provided you with an answer in Python, will you be able to understand the idea and try to port it over to Java?

Comment: @eshirima I know nothing about Python, but I can try.

Comment: See my updated answer. Don't forget to mark as answer and upvote if it helps solve your problem

Comment: @eshirima thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same logic can be translated into Java. Just Google around to see how to open a directory and iterate through its files in Java. The code and comments should be self-explanatory.

```
def loadImagesFrom(folder):

    for filename in os.listdir(folder): #iterate through the files inside the folder
        print 'FileName', filename

        # At this point, filename is just a string consisting of the file's given title.
        # Simply passing that into OpenCV, will not work because that filename does not exist in the
        # current directory. The file is located in folder/filename. In order to get the exact path,
        # we use os.path.join. The final result will look something like this: /Images/car.png
        # Thereafter we simply feed the path to OpenCV's imread'

        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))

        # check to see if the image is not empty first.
        # You can do this as well by checking if image.shape.isEmpty() or something along these lines

        if image is not None:
            # Do stuff with your image
        else:
            # Image is empty
```

**EDIT 1**
[Iterate through folder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java)