# Lazy iterator over files in directory structure

Tags: java, iterator, directory-tree

There are related questions, but none of them addresses the "lazy" part, that is, discover more content only as the iteration progresses.

See [How do I iterate through the files in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java)

Also Apache Commons FileUtils.iterateFiles() reads all files into a Collection (List) at first before getting the Iterator on that.

I have a nested directory structure with a large amount of files (2 million). My goal is to iterate the files without having to read all the names into a collection.

Comment: Python os.walk?  :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I don't think OP wants to wait two hours until it's finished :)

Comment: @Tobias. Then why use Java? :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Right, you're correct. But even for Python, os.walk is REALLY slow.

Comment: @Tobias. I haven't noticed it to be so.

Comment: @joopRksn, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. You might want to explain more about what you mean by lazy loading, maybe giving an example with Stream...

Comment: Not a single answer for a question about such basic functionality? Unreal...