# Java - traverse through folders and do something if intended folder is present

Tags: java

Being very new to Java, I'm unable to bring a small concept to a syntactic form. Apologies.

My project structure looks like below & i'm trying to walk thru the sub folders of  `applications`
directory & search for a folder named `conduit`, if present, create a new folder called `base` parallel to it.

At best I came up with the below code, post that, kind of struggling.

```
/home/project_A/applications
                |sub_project_A
                  |target
                    |conduit
                |sub_project_B
                  |target
                    |conduit

                |sub_project_C
                  |target
                    |class

                |sub_project_D
                  |target
                    |conduit    

public class Test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    String appDir = s + "/applications";
    System.out.println("Directory Exists" + appDir);

  }
 }
```

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154523/5601284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BFS to traverse the sub directories:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    Queue<Path> paths = new LinkedList<>();
    paths.add(currentRelativePath);
    while(!paths.isEmpty()) {
        Path current = paths.poll();
        File currentFile = current.toFile();
        if(currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            if(currentFile.getName().equals("conduit")) {
                // Found the directory called conduit, Do what you have to do here
            }else {
                for(String fileName : currentFile.list()) {
                    paths.add(Paths.get(currentFile.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName)); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: not that it is wrong, but what is the reasoning for using BFS? i think DFS would work just as well...for each folder, call recursively on each subfolder, until you find "conduit" and then create "base" and return. DFS is just easier to write.

Comment: @TomElias yeah, it can be solved by both BFS and DFS, I just gave an example of BFS because I think it would be easier for a new java developer to understand quickly.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed : Really appreciate your help here.. Is it possible for you to explain what exactly `Queue<Path> paths = new LinkedList<>();` does and why we need this ? thanks again

Comment: @ChelMS, Queue<> is an interface in java which has the methods to implement the Queue Data Structure and LinkedList is one of the many implementation of Queue interface in java. (javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

We need a queue to implement BFS algorithm.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed: It works for the parent directory but incase of the folder `conduit` is present in sub directories its not working..what changes should I be making here, thanks

Comment: @ChelMS : just update the line inside the for loop 
from
paths.add(Path.of(fileName));

to

paths.add(Paths.get(currentFile.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName));

Then it will work for all the sub directories..

Comment: @ChelMS I have updated the solution I answered before, you can use the solution without any change.. This is working for sub-directories..

Comment: @Shibbir Ahmed : Really appreciate your help here !! `file.mkdir()` dont take arguments, but my requirement is when `conduit` folder is spotted , `base` folder has to be created along side to `conduit`, so I tried the below in the if loop 
`File newDir = new File("base");
newDir.mkdir()` and this is not working..  Could you please correct me here, thanks a lot again

Comment: @ChelMS you have to put the absolute path of the file to create it. Thus, your base directory creation should look like: File newDir = new File(current.getParent()+"/base"); newDir.mkdir();

Comment: thanks a lot @ShibbirAhmed .. Really appreciate the support..

Answer (score 1):

Using `Files.find` is a good way to traverse a series of directories quickly to find files or directories matching any criteria you need. Here is an example which prints off the matches:

```
BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> a.isDirectory() && "conduit".equals(p.getFileName().toString());
try(var dirs = Files.find(Path.of("."), Integer.MAX_VALUE, predicate)) {
    dirs.forEach(p -> {
            System.out.println("Found "+p+", create if not exists: "+p.resolveSibling("base"));
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting below errors, what am I doing incorrect ?
`test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
  BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> a.isDirectory() && "conduit".equals(p.getFileName().toString());
  ^
  symbol:   class BiPredicate
  location: class test
test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
  BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> a.isDirectory() && "conduit".equals(p.getFileName().toString());
                    ^
  symbol:   class BasicFileAttributes
  location: class test`

Comment: `import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> a.isDirectory() && "conduit".equals(p.getFileName().toString());
  try(var dirs = Files.find(Path.of("."), Integer.MAX_VALUE, predicate)) {
    dirs.forEach(p -> {
            System.out.println("Found "+p+", create if not exists: "+p.resolveSibling("base"));
        }
    );
   }
 }
}`

Comment: Just replace `predicate` by its definition `(p,a) -> a.isDirectory() && "conduit".equals(p.getFileName().toString())` in the final parameter of `Files.find`, then you don't need to import `BiPredicate` and `BasicFileAttributes`

Comment: I imported `import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes; and 
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;` but now facing below error..
`10: error: cannot find symbol
  try(var dirs = Files.find(Path.of("."), Integer.MAX_VALUE, predicate)) {
      ^
  symbol:   class var
  location: class one`

Comment: You are using an old JDK, upgrade to newer JDK or try replacing  `var` by `Stream<Path>`.

Comment: Cool, thank you !!