# I cannot access the correct MANIFEST.MF file in my java code

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

I have tried numerous ways to access the manifest from the correct jar in a unit test.
The issue I have is it seems to be reading the first jar file it comes to and not the one for my class.
This is my latest attempt

```
InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
try {
    if (is == null) {
        System.out.println("null no input stream");
    } else {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        v = attributes.getValue("Test");
        System.out.println("Test="+v);
        v = attributes.getValue("Created-by");
        System.out.println("By="+v);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("error");
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

And these are the results

`Test=null
By=1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)`

The `MANIFEST.MF` I want to use has a value for `Test`, so I know this is reading the wrong file

Does anyone know how I can specify the jar which contains the manifest file for the unit test to use?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with.....  note replace `HTMLDocumen`t with your class/object.

```
   HTMLDocument htmlDoc = new HTMLDocument();

    try
    {
      JarFile jarfile = new JarFile(htmlDoc.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

      // Get the manifest
      Manifest manifest = jarfile.getManifest();

      Map<String,Attributes> msa = manifest.getEntries();

      for (String key : msa.keySet())
      {
        System.out.println("KEY: " + key);

        Attributes a = msa.get(key);

        for (Object k : a.keySet())
        {
          System.out.println(k + " - " + a.get(k));
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader();
try {
  URL url = classLoader.findResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
  Manifest manifest = new Manifest(url.openStream());
  // add your code
  ...
} catch (IOException E) {
  // handle exception
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that is still giving me the same incorrect result ... 
Test=null 
By=1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Comment: He already read the file, otherwise the output would've been: _null no input stream_

Answer (score 1):

You can access the jar that contains your class with:

```
InputStream in = MyClass
                .class
                .getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation()
                .openStream();
```

I changed this line in your code and got the same results though, [you might want to walk and read the whole jar your self](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061589/20654) until you find the manifest file and then read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

*"Test"* is not a [main attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes).

Try [getEntries()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html#getEntries%28%29) and look up your custom attribute there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method i finally used ...

```
String path = Test.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

    path = path.replace("classes/", "");

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("jar:file:"+path+"test.jar!/");
        JarURLConnection jarConnection = null;
        try {
            jarConnection = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            Manifest manifest = jarConnection.getManifest();

            java.util.jar.Attributes manifestItem = manifest.getMainAttributes();
            System.out.println(manifestItem.getValue("Test"));
            System.out.println(manifestItem.getValue("Implementation-Version"));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Its pretty dirty with all that path manipulation and hard coding of the jar name...
Does this matter? thank you once again!