# URL to a resource within JAR

Tags: java, url, wsdl

I need to get URL to a resource within a jar file. I use this URL as an argument to my service call. My below code fails with "No such File or Directory" error.

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("AXLAPI.wsdl").getFile());
final URL wsdlURL = new URL(this.getClass().getResource(this.getClass().getSimpleName() +".class"),file.toString());
String endpoint = "https://<machine>:8443/axl/";
AXLAPIService ss = new AXLAPIService( wsdlURL );
```

Below is the error am seeing on executing this -

```
Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/blah/blah/blah.jar!/AXLAPI.wsdl. It failed with: 
/blah/blah/blah.jar!/AXLAPI.wsdl (No such file or directory).
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions to handle this !

Comment: File from Jar is no longer an independent File

Comment: right.. But I am trying relative path to the jar file as the exclamation indicates. Jar -xvf shows my wsdl file at the root path of the jar file

Comment: This may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct url should be

`jar:file:/blah/blah/blah.jar!/AXLAPI.wsdl`