# Is there an equivalent to Files.newDirectoryStream for resources on the classpath

Tags: java, classpath, java-7, nio

I have a project that uses this code to get a filtered list of files in a directory:

```
Path directoryPath = 
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src/main/resources/com/foo/bar");
DirectoryStream<Path> ds = 
    Files.newDirectoryStream(directoryPath, filter);
```

This works great when I run the project in eclipse, but when we package up the jar, of course, it can't find the resources using this path.  I could manually reference these resources if I knew their names ahead of time, but I'm hitting a wall trying to easily filter them, or even get a list of them.  Is there a clean way to do this that references these files as resources instead of a specific directory location?

Comment: `"src/main/resources/com/foo/bar"` is already a problem. Your `src` directory won't be there at runtime. You should be using `Class.getResource()` and friends, not files and paths.

Comment: I would normally reference all of these as resources, but I have thus far been able to find any way to filter resources at runtime, the way Files.newDirectoryStream(path, globFilter) does.  For example, if you want to load all the resources in a directory specified by command-line arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Class.getResource or Class.getResourceAsStream and see if that works for you.

Comment: It seems I didn't read your question thoroughly enough :-S  have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly or the second answer to this if you're willing to go to this extent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012819/how-can-i-get-a-resource-folder-from-inside-my-jar-file

Comment: Thanks, @user1181247.  I was able to use the information in the first link you posted to come up with a solution.