# java8-cucumber-java8 sprinboot application

Tags: cucumber-java

I am trying to run .feature from java main application or say a spring boot application rather going through Junit approach. I am facing issues to run it from main. somehow i tried to run from main by using Main.main call in eclipse but when i packaged to in .jar or deployed to openshift it started throwing No backend module found exception. Could anyone of you please help me to find a way on it?
I am using java8 and cucumber-java8 dependency

e.g

```
Main.main(new String[] { "-g", "com.test.helloworld", "C:\\Users\\<user.name>\\git1\\test-helloworld\\src\\main\\resources\\helloworld.feature" });
```

I would like to try this with plain java main class. In eclipse its able to execute without any hassles but when i tries in jar/openshift its unable to load feature or backend modules.

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot uses a nested jar structure that requires the use of `ApplicationContext.getResources` to access it transparently. As such you'll have to implement a resource loader for Cucumber that utilizes the application context.

See also:

- [Cucumber: no backend found when running from Spring Boot jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069165/cucumber-no-backend-found-when-running-from-spring-boot-jar)
- [Feature files can not read from Spring boot structure.](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1320#issuecomment-367503875)