# How to execute Cucumber Spring Boot Packaged Jar from command line?

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am fairly new to cucumber-jvm world. Trying to package cucumber spring boot app as Jar. app runs fine from Eclipse. But when I package as executable jar it fails with Exception :

Exception in Main Thread, No backend Module found. Make sure that you have backend module on CLASSPATH. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: DO you have jars like cucumber-java, cucumber-core etc etc in the classpath? This error is thrown when implementation of Backend.java is not found in cucumber.runtime package. Refer to line 56 at- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v2.4.0/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/Runtime.java

Comment: Yes I do have cucumber-java, cucumber-core 1.2.5 on classpath. And I can see the JavaBackend class in cucumber.runtime package.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1320

SpringBoot uses a nested jar structure that requires the use of `ApplicationContext.getResources` to access it transparently. You'll have to create your own instance of the Cucumber runtime and provide it a class loader and resource loader that use the `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gradle, place the Cucumber artifacts (ie features, step implementations, etc) into a subproject, eg `my-cucumber-tests`, separate from the Spring Boot app.

Then in the Spring Boot app's `build.gradle`, add:

```
bootJar {
  // make backend, features, and steps available to Cucumber at runtime
  requiresUnpack '**/my-cucumber-tests-*.jar', '**/cucumber-java-*.jar'
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What exactly goes into this subproject and what stays at the "main" project?

Comment: The `my-cucumber-tests` subproject contains the Cucumber features, step implementations, etc. The `main` project, ideally (although we haven't yet achieved the ideal) contains the `main` function and everything else that's server-related. Ideally there's a separation of concerns: one subproject is server-related code and the other subproject is Cucumber-related code.