# Referencing an image in a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am having real trouble referencing a simple image in a jar file.

I have a package `au.com.mysite.pdf` tha contains the java files
I have a package `au.com.mysite.pdf.res` tha contains images

In my java file I reference an image like this
`getClass().getResource("/au/com/mysite/pdf/res/logo.png").getPath()`

but the image can never be found.  In the debutter it looks like this
`/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/myname/workspace/gnupdf/bin/au/com/mysite/pdf/res/logo.png`

What is with the leading '/' and the separators are not correct for windows.

I checked this path and it does not work in MS Explorer.

### UPDATE

Ok, it is working to some extent except the image path is not correct, `/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/myname/workspace/gnupdf/bin/au/com/mysite/pdf/res/logo.png` is not a reference to a file, what is with the leading slash and the %20 space characters?  How do I convert this into a file URL instead of a web url?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but as a general matter Windows handles forward slashes as path separators just fine.

Comment: You should also make sure your image really is in the jar in the right directory with `jar tf myjar.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in a jar, getResource is not going to return anything useful. getResourceAsStream is probably what you want.

Comment: The API takes a string as the location of the file

Comment: What API are you trying to use? My point is that there is no file, only a bunch of bytes inside the jar. Most apis will allow you to specify the input as a stream rather than a file location, which is what you will need.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you why that's not working, but when I reference images I have stored in a jar, typically for menu icon images, I use:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/package/sub_package/image_name.png"));
```

This has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using getResource from a .jar will work.
A couple things: 
What's the Class-Path of your .jar file's Manifest?
Files inside of a .jar are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

I saw what your problem might be. You're trying to get the path, but that's not necessary because anyway you won't be able to reference it.

Instead do this:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("images/image01.png));
```

And then you can use your image within a java program.

See this for instance:

[How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/list-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: The file is definately inside the jar