# Listing xml files in a jar file

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I have a 3rd party jar that contains a number of xml files that i'd like to process. I don't know the name or number
of xml files but i do know the folder where they are packaged within the jar.

```
URL url = this.class.getResource("/com/arantech/touchpoint/index");
System.out.println(url.toString());
```

this seems to return a valid file (folder) path

```
jar:file:/home/.m2/repository/com/abc/tp-common/5.2.0/tp-common-5.2.0.jar!/com/abc/tp/index
```

but when i attempt to list the files in the folder i always get a NullPointerException

```
File dir = new File(url.toString());
System.out.println(dir.exists());
System.out.println(dir.listFiles().length);
```

Any guidance?

Comment: That *isn't* a valid folder path, it's a synthetic URL that points at a resource inside a JAR file. You can't treat the contents of JAR files as though they were themselves files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

With this you could traverse the main folder:

```
URL url = this.class.getResource("/com/arantech/touchpoint/index");
JarFile jar;       
System.out.println("Loading JAR from: " + url.toString());

JarURLConnection URLcon = (JarURLConnection)(url.openConnection());
jar = URLcon.getJarFile();

Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements())
{
  JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
  if (entry.isDirectory() || !entry.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
    continue;

  InputStream inputStream = null;
  try
  {
    inputStream = jar.getInputStream(entry);
    if (inputStream != null)
    {
      // TODO: Load XML from inputStream
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot load JAR: " + url);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (inputStream != null)
      inputStream.close();          
  }
}
jar.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jar is a Zip file, so listing files within a Jar could be done with:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("your.jar");
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(zipEntries.nextElement().getName());
}
```

[ZipEntry.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName%28%29) contains entry path (although it's not documented) so you can detect the ones that you need by using something like [String.startsWith("your/path")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).