# Creating File object for Jar root

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have an executable jar with a series of properties files within at the root level of which I  want to **read** from. I want to make use of `FileUtils` `listFiles()` to pickup all of these files.

myjar.jar
->a.properties
->b.properties
->c.properties
etc...

The issue I am having is creating a File object representing the properties files parent directory (the jar root).

I understand by the use of `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` etc I can pickup the files individually. But I want them all in a list.

If I use:

`new File(RunUI.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());`

The absolutepath is:

`C:\projects\temp\MYTOOLS\selenium-plugin\target\file:\C:\projects\temp\MYT
OOLS\selenium-plugin\target\selenium-plugin-complete-0.0.1.jar!\main\selenium-plugin-0.0.1.jar`

but this is obviously not accepted as a directory and so throws a null pointer when trying to use listFiles.

My question is thus, is it possible for me to make use of the jar root as a traditional File object directory?

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: "I want to make use of FileUtils listFiles() to pickup all of these files." Bad luck, you can't. Entries in a JAR file are not Files.