# NullPointer Exception while read audio files

Tags: java, audio, jar, executable-jar

I made a program to read audio files.
At first I did it with absolute path because it's easyer to develop.

Then I cahnge it to relative path because I want to compress it to a `*jar`. 
So I code this method(at first only short later the code:

```
1.: at first I make a FileArray to save the Files
2.: make the array to save the AudioClip
3.: for loop to read the Clips
```

Now the code:

```
    private AudioClip[] liesAudioDateien (File inputFile) {
        File[] dateFileArray;
        AudioClip[] tracks;
        dateFileArray = inputFile.listFiles();
        tracks = new AudioClip[dateFileArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
            if (dateFileArray[i].isFile()) {
                try {
                    tracks[i] = Applet.newAudioClip(dateFileArray[i].toURL());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Error!: -- " + ex.toString());
                }
            }

        }
        return tracks;   
    }
```

`inputFile.listfiles()` returns null, as seems my path isn't OK. 
But my path is Ok, because I let it print on the command line.
`D:\Eclipse\MyProjekt\dist\MyProject.jar\audio`.
In NetBeans, it does work. `If I make a jar file, it doesn't work.`

I have already try:

1. `D:\Eclipse\MyProjekt\dist\MyProject.jar\audio\`
2. `/` in place of `\`

Comment: How do you execute your jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the correct file path?

```
D:\Eclipse\MyProjekt\dist\MyProject.jar\audio
```

The audio directory is in a **folder called MyProject.jar**?

If your audio files are within the .jar file you cannot use the `File` class to list them. What you have to do instead is [read the entries from the .jar file, like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file).

Comment: My jar file call MyProjekt.jar. It is wrong? In Myprojekt.jar containes 'audio, source, images'