# Managing directories in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need to access directory with levels descriptions in my game.

```
Gdx.files.internal("data/levels");
```

On Android it works fine, but on desktop `levels` is not recognized as a directory and also `list()` returns null. Why it happens and what is the solution? I use maven as my build tool, I've checked that the .jar contains all necessary assets.

I've found hack:

```
Gdx.files.internal("./bin/data/levels");
```

but it obviously works only in development environment, which is not satisfactory.

Comment: Have you configured the desktop project `build path` to point to its assets?

Comment: Yes, I have. In resources tag.

Comment: Maybe you should end the path with a slash : "data/levels/"

Comment: I've tried, it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Gdx.files.local("data/levels")`

See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling, and note that "internal" files are searched for via the CLASSPATH.  Listing "directories" on the classpath is not implemented (and is unlikely to be listed).

Comment: On desktop it will return directory relative to application working directory, not the one inside jar. I've tested it, assume I have `somefile` packed in my jar inside data dir.
`Gdx.files.local("data/somefile").exists()`
will return false, while
`Gdx.files.internal("data/somefile").exists()`
returns true.

Why listing directories on classpath is not implemented? Is it a big issue?

Comment: Yeah, listing the contents of a "directory" in a jar file or on the classpath is not supported.  I believe the general case is ugly because a "directory" could span multiple entries on the classpath.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file/1429275 for some work-arounds.  For your Libgdx probably just generate a file that contains the list of files to side-step the issue.