# load a folder from a jar

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to access a directory inside my jar file. I want to go through every of the files inside the directory itself. I tried using the following:

```
File[] files = new File("ressources").listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(file.getAbsolutePath());
            // some work
        }
```

If I test this, it works well. But once I put the contents into the jar, it doesn't because of several reasons. If I use this code, the URL always points outside the jar.

structure of my project :

```
src 
   controllers
   models
         class that containt traitement
   views
ressources
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Basically, you just use a ZipInputStream to find a list of files (a .jar is the same as a .zip)

Once you know the names of the files, you can use getClass().getResource(String path) to get the URL to the file.

Comment: First i well create executable jar containt some ressources, my programm it work with IDE but jar no

Answer (score 0):

I presume this `jar` is on your classpath.

You can list all the files in a directory using the `ClassLoader`.

First you can get a list of the file names then you can get `URL`s from the `ClassLoader` for individual files:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String base = "/path/to/folder/inside/jar";
    final List<URL> urls = new LinkedList<>();
    try (final Scanner s = new Scanner(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(base))) {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            urls.add(MyClass.class.getResource(base + "/" + s.nextLine()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(urls);
}
```

You can do whatever you want with the `URL` - either read and `InputStream` into memory or copy the `InputStream` into a `File` on your hard disc.

Note that this definitely works with the `URLClassLoader` which is the default, if you are using an applet or a custom `ClassLoader` then this approach may not work.

**NB:**

You have a typo - its `resources` not `ressources`.

You should use [reverse domain name notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) for your project, this is the convention.

Comment: I modify string base to my folder /ressources and i get this exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: @ELMEKKIAnouar Have you checked your typos? And I assume you have used the correct `class` for the class reference.

Comment: i rename my folder to resources but i get always exception

Comment: Can you unpack your jar to ensure that the folder is in there?

Comment: i unpack jar i didt found resources i get all files directly in root

Comment: @ELMEKKIAnouar Well then your build process is broken not the code.

Comment: how can organized files in folder, files xml

Comment: @ELMEKKIAnouar You will have to post a question for that, describing your build process.

Comment: please i have more than 100 files XML i wanna to parse all files with some traitement my programm work with ide but not with jar executable.

Comment: I need to push all files in directory