# JBoss wildfly 8.x Provider "vfs" not installed when using java nio Paths

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to export my spring application from glassfish 4 to JBoss wildfly 8.x or 9 alpha, but when my application starts in some part of my code throws the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "vfs" not installed
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:218)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "vfs" not installed
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at com.springmvcangular.backend.utils.entity.BaseEntityInitializer.extendsEntities(BaseEntityInitializer.java:123)
    at com.springmvcangular.backend.utils.entity.BaseEntityInitializer.initializeBaseEntities(BaseEntityInitializer.java:88)
    at com.springmvcangular.backend.config.ApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ApplicationInitializer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:178)
    ... 7 more
```

in my class `BaseEntityInitializer` in that exception line i have:

```
packagepath = Paths.get(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResource(path.replace('.', '/')).toURI());
```

where `path` its a package path like `com.something.model`, so why in my glassfish 4 server this works perfectly and what i need for use it in wildfly? i don't know what is missing in wildfly or if i need to include some library.

Answer (score 5):

It happens to work by chance in GlassFish. Nowhere in the `ClassLoader` contract (or the Java EE platform specification) is it specified what kind of `URL` you get back. In the GlassFish ClasLoder it probably happens to be a `jar://` or `file://` URL for which there happens to be a FileSystemProvider (`jar://` only by accident BTW). In WildFly the `URL` happens to be a JBoss VFS URL. There are various hacks that you can apply to make it work for now but they all can't hide the fact that you're relying on not portable behavior. You're better off using something like `URL#openStream()` instead which is portable and should therefore work everywhere.

**Update**

What you can try to do is doing more at compile time. Options include:

- Do the transformation with Javassist at compile time. This also reduces the chances of conflicts with the Javassist shipping with WildFly.
- Gather the information about the resources at compile time and store it in a file at a well known location. You can have the same file name in multiple JARs as `ClassLoader#getResources(String)` can return multiple results.

If you provide more specific information about the problem you're trying to solve I may be able to give more specific answers.

Comment: thanks,do you have a code example or an url where i can see how to use it for the Paths class?

Comment: What do you need the `Path` for? Do you just want to read a resource or do you want to list all resources in a folder?

Comment: i need to read all resources in a folder(package) and get their names like com.package.otherpachage.classname, because i'm using javassist so how i can read a package resources using inputstreams or how can install vfs for java nio? i don't find anything about it

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution how to iterate over files/directories in Wildfly:

```
List<String> fileNames = new LinkedList<>();
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/your/path");
VirtualJarInputStream virtualJarInputStream = (VirtualJarInputStream) resourceUrl.openStream();
JarEntry next = null;
while ((next = virtualJarInputStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
    fileNames.add(next.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    import org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile; // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-vfs

    URLConnection connection = Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/template/cyber")).openConnection();
    VirtualFile virtualFile = (VirtualFile) connection.getContent();
    Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get(virtualFile.getPhysicalFile().toURI()));
    List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```