# Reading Path of .class files inside a .jar file with java

Tags: java, jar

I have a `.jar` file. Inside this file there are many `.class` files.
I need to get the list of qualified pathnames of every `.class` file in this `.jar` file.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: A jar file is simply a renamed zip file, so you could open it as a zip and scan through all ZipEntries.

Comment: Maybe this answer could be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file