# How to get files in directory of jar file in java?

Tags: java, maven, resources, directory, classpath

assume that i have this code in a project `A`:

```
public class test {
    public void myMethod() {
          String directoryPath = classLoader.getResource("") + "/templates/code/";
          // code to read directory files
    }
}
```

**First Problem**

and have some specific files in `resources/templates` directory of this project. and want to get all of the files that in the `resources/templates` directory.

I'm added that project as a dependency to another project named `B` and want to call `myMethod`.

now, the `myMethod` works fine when calling in project `A`, but when i'm call it in `B` project it throws `FileNotFoundException`.

I'm call the `myMethod` in project `B` as you seen below:

```
public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           myMethod();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

1- Both of that projects is Spring, Maven project

2- When i build project `B`, the jar file of project `A` is in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

First you could use getResource to work with files as follow :

```
    URL directoryPath = classLoader.getResource("resources/templates");
    File f = new File(directoryPath.getFile());
```

BUT, once your application is deployed as a jar, you can't access the ressources with "File" anymore. You need to read the content of the jar file.

Here's a link to help you : [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)