# Get the size of a resource

Tags: java, scala

I'm using `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` to read from bundle resources.

How can I know the file size before reading the entire stream?

I can't access them with `getClass().getResource(path).toURI()` when it's packaged, so that won't work.

Comment: Why is the file size important? If it's in a jar, it's likely to be compressed.

Comment: Does `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path).available()` return the correct file size?

Comment: @Buddy, no. `"Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream [...] by the next invocation of a method"`

Comment: Granted, `getClass().getResource(path).toURI()` does not work, when the application is packaged, on the other hand, you don’t want a URI, you want the size of the resource, so why do you care whether `.toURI()` works? `getClass().getResource(path).openConnection().getContentLength()` *does* work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Naturally you cannot query the total size of a stream, since by definition it does not make the whole file available to you. Think of popping your hand in a river. You have a piece of the stream,but you have to put the entire river in your hand to know the total volume.

In this case, you have to read the entire file as a stream and count the size. Remember you are dealing with classes and resources that may be part of a JAR file or other kind of compressed resource. The classloader does not have to provide a file handle to the resource in this case

Comment: I have a few JS files and a HTML file that I wish to serve with Netty, how would you suggest I bundle those files and allow them to be efficiently served over HTTP? I need the file size for the content-length header.

Comment: The OP is not asking about a stream, he's telling that he's "using getResourceAsStream(path)", but needs to "know file size before reading". While the answer is right about the general `InputStream`, but it's not the question. Resources do have their size on the filesystem or in ZIP header. The fact that this information is not available is a sad shortcoming of the API.

Answer (score 7):

I tried answer to this post [Ask for length of a file read from Classpath in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792105/ask-for-length-of-a-file-read-from-classpath-in-java?noredirect=1#comment100143772_56792105) but they marked it as duplicated of your question so i give my answer here!

It's possible to get the size of a simple file using:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/roberto/Desktop/bar/file.txt");
long length = file.length();
System.out.println("Length: " + length);
```

---

When `file.txt` is packaged in a jar the `.length()` will return always 0.
So we need to use `JarFile`:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("C:/Users/roberto/Desktop/bar/foo.jar");
Object size = jarFile.getEntry("file.txt").getSize();
System.out.println("Size: " + size.toString())
```

You can get the compressed size too:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("C:/Users/roberto/Desktop/bar/foo.jar");
Object compressedSize = jarFile.getEntry("file.txt").getCompressedSize();
System.out.println("CompressedSize: " + compressedSize);
```

---

It's still possible getting the size of a file packaged in a jar using the `jar` command:

```
jar tvf Desktop\bar\foo.jar file.txt
```

Output will be: `5 Thu Jun 27 17:36:10 CEST 2019 file.txt`
where `5` is the size.

You can use it in the code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar tvf C:/Users/roberto/Desktop/bar/foo.jar file.txt");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), writer, Charset.defaultCharset());
String jarOutput = writer.toString();
```

but jdk is required to run the `jar` command.

Answer (score 0):

This question has some specific solutions: [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file), specifically, using a [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) API since Java 7.

It should work for files in a JAR and unpacked files. I'm not sure it will work for a JAR packed in a WAR, for instance.