# Ask for length of a file read from Classpath in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to after referencing a file in the classpath (which may be in a jar file which is compressed) to get the length of that file or do I just have to read the whole thing?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: URL file = ...
    Path path = Paths.get(file.toURI());
    long size = Files.size(path):

Comment: @RobertoManfreda: how will your suggestion work for a resource held within a jar (as the OP is requesting)?

Comment: @RobertoManfreda That would qualify as “read the whole thing,” which Dean implies he wants to avoid.

Comment: My answer ih here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360826/get-the-size-of-a-resource/56797810#56797810