# Coded path from getResource() doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this folder

```
File imagesOrg = new File(getClass().getResource("/stock").getPath());
```

I've printed it out in console with

```
 System.out.println(imagesOrg.getAbsolutePath());
```

and there is a space within my path so it was changed to %20 and because of that the rest of my code doesn't work which is:

```
 for(final File child : imagesOrg.listFiles()) {
                    System.out.println(child.getName());
 }
```

If I put the whole path in new File with a space instead of %20 it works fine is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: I'd think `getResourceAsStream()` would be better here.  Resources will not always be files.

Comment: @markspace could you give me a sample?

Comment: Google for `java getresourceasstream example`  you can find the sample within first 10 results

Comment: @AdrianShum I did that and I've tried             new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("images").toString());
with no results

Comment: This may interest you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28057735/1393766

Comment: You call toString against a stream? What are you expecting it to do?!

Answer (score 0):

I recommand URL decoder.

You can use like this..

String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");