# Kotlin: get list of all files in resource folder

Tags: kotlin, resources, classpath

Is there a way to get list of all files in "resources" folder in Kotlin?

I can read specific file as

```
Application::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/folder/filename.ext")
```

But sometimes I just want to extract everything from folder "folder" to an external directory.

Answer (score 15):

As I struggled with the same issue and couldn't find a concrete answer, so I had to write one myself.

Here is my solution:

```
fun getAllFilesInResources()
{
    val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
    val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/src/main/resources")
    val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
                    .filter { item -> Files.isRegularFile(item) }
                    .filter { item -> item.toString().endsWith(".txt") }
                    .forEach { item -> println("filename: $item") }
}
```

Here I have parsed through all the files in the ***/src/main/resources*** folder and then filtered only the regular files (no directories included) and then filtered for the text files within the resources directory.

The output is a list of all the absolute file paths with the extension ***.txt*** in the resources folder. Now you can use these paths to copy the files to an external folder.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by debug and jar? did you mean filtering jar files? in that case all you need to do is replace the .txt with .jar and you will filter only jar files.

Comment: When you pack to a jar the procedure in Java is different. I guess this is applicable for Kotlin as well.

Comment: Refering to `"/src/main/resources"` will not work within a bundled JAR file

Comment: Used this to write a file to the resources directory in Compose Desktop, with one change: " val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().plus("/src/jvmMain/resources") "

Comment: You should NOT refer to /src - this is never a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

The task has two distinct parts:

1. Obtain a file that represents the resource directory
2. Traverse the directory

For **1** you can use Java's `getResource`:

```
val dir = File( object {}.javaClass.getResource(directoryPath).file )
```

For **2** you can use Kotlin's [File.walk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/walk.html) extension function that returns a [sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/) of files you can process, e.g:

```
dir.walk().forEach { f ->
    if(f.isFile) {
        println("file ${f.name}")
    } else {
        println("dir ${f.name}")
    }
}
```

Put together you may end up with the following code:

```kotlin
fun onEachResource(path: String, action: (File) -> Unit) {

    fun resource2file(path: String): File {
        val resourceURL = object {}.javaClass.getResource(path)
        return File(checkNotNull(resourceURL, { "Path not found: '$path'" }).file)
    }

    with(resource2file(path)) {
        this.walk().forEach { f -> action(f) }
    }
}
```

so that if you have `resources/nested` direcory, you can:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    
    val print = { f: File ->
        when (f.isFile) {
            true -> println("[F] ${f.absolutePath}")
            false -> println("[D] ${f.absolutePath}")
        }
    }
    
    onEachResource("/nested", print)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are no methods for it (i.e. `Application::class.java.listFilesInDirectory("/folder/")`), but you can create your own system to list the files in a directory:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun getResourceFiles(path: String): List<String> = getResourceAsStream(path).use{
    return if(it == null) emptyList()
    else BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(it)).readLines()
}

private fun getResourceAsStream(resource: String): InputStream? = 
        Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource) 
                ?: resource::class.java.getResourceAsStream(resource)
```

Then just call `getResourceFiles("/folder/")` and you'll get a list of files in the folder, assuming it's in the classpath.

This works because Kotlin has an extension function that reads lines into a List of Strings. The declaration is:

```
/**
 * Reads this reader content as a list of lines.
 *
 * Do not use this function for huge files.
 */
public fun Reader.readLines(): List<String> {
    val result = arrayListOf<String>()
    forEachLine { result.add(it) }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Am I wrong that your function can be reduced to
`    private fun getResourceList(path: String): List<String> {
        val stream = Application::class.java.getResourceAsStream(path) ?: return emptyList()
        return stream.bufferedReader().use { it.readLines() }
    }
`

Comment: `resource::class.java` will always refer to `String::class.java` which might not be what you intended

Comment: @SimonForsberg I have no idea what I was thinking. It's still only a fallback at least, so `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource)` at least takes precedence over whatever I thought of there

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to iterate over [JAR-packed resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file) on JVM:

```
fun iterateResources(resourceDir: String) {
    val resource = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().classLoader.getResource(resourceDir)
        ?: error("Resource $resourceDir was not found")
    FileSystems.newFileSystem(resource.toURI(), emptyMap<String, String>()).use { fs ->
        Files.walk(fs.getPath(resourceDir))
            .filter { it.extension == "ttf" }
            .forEach { file -> println(file.toUri().toString()) }
    }
}
```