# how to get all *.json files in a jar programatically?

Tags: java

say under my src/main/resources folder I have several .json files, how can I write java code to retrieve a list containing all those files?

it seems that `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources` doesn't support wildcard matching.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is worth an answer given the duplicates, but you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429275/6358346) to get a list of resource files from the JAR, and then while iterating though the list check if the file is a json file using `zip.getNextEntry().getName().endsWith(".json")`... if it is, add it to your new list.