# EAR deployment with EJB and JAR in JBoss Wildfly - how to load all files in folder or resources in JAR from within EJB project?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wildfly, ear

I want to load and process json schema files from within two different deployments, the first being a **WAR** with JAX-RS endpoint and the second an **EAR** with Singleton-**EJB** + a resources **JAR** containing the schema files (I've read that packaging resources files for use in EJBs is only possible when bundling them in a separate JAR inside the EAR).

Development environment is eclipse 2019-03 with JBoss Wildfly 16.

### WAR deployment with JAX-RS endpoint

The WAR part is fine, I have an `@ApplicationScoped` Bean and can access the schema files located in `src/main/webapp/schemas/` via ServletContext, see the following code snippet:

```
@ForWarDeployment
@ApplicationScoped
public class JsonSchemaValidatorWar extends JsonSchemaValidatorBase {
...
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Consumer<Path> readSchema = schemaFile -> {
        String schemaName = schemaFile.getName(schemaFile.getNameCount() - 1).toString();
        JsonSchema js = jvs.readSchema(schemaFile);
        map.put(schemaName, js); // this is a concurrent hash map in base class
        log.info("Schema " + schemaName + " added: " + js.toJson());
    };
    URI schemaFolder;
    try {
        schemaFolder = servletContext.getResource("/schemas").toURI();
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(schemaFolder))) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(readSchema);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading schema files!", e);
    }
}
```

Output on first request:

> ... (default task-1) Schema person.schema.json added: {"$id": ...

### EAR deployment with EJB and resources JAR

The EJB part is tricky, I haven't found a solution for reading all schema files yet.

What I currently have is a multi-module maven project with the following structure:

```
- parent
- | ear 
- | ejb3
- | resources
```

### pom.xml for parent project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mdv</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>json-ejb3</module>
    <module>json-ear</module>
    <module>json-resources</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

### pom.xml for ear project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mdv</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>json-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mdv</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-ejb3</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mdv</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>7</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <earSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### pom.xml for resources project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mdv</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>json-resources</artifactId>
</project>
```

### pom.xml for ejb3 project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mdv</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>json-ejb3</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <!-- contains a json schema processing library and the class JsonSchemaValidatorEjb -->
            <groupId>mdv</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### The problem with loading schema files in EJB

I want to load the schema files in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean for use in a Singleton EJB, the corresponding class is `JsonSchemaValidatorService`:

```
package mdv;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import json.ForEjbDeployment;
import json.IJsonSchemaValidator;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class JsonSchemaValidatorService {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("JsonSchemaValidatorService");

    @Inject
    @ForEjbDeployment
    IJsonSchemaValidator jsonSchemaValidator;
    // this is where json schema files should be loaded

    public JsonSchemaValidatorService() {
        //
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Started JsonSchemaValidatorService.");
        log.info("Loaded schemas in jsonSchemaValidator: " + jsonSchemaValidator.getLoadedSchemas());
    }

}
```

The class for loading json schema files in EJB environment is this bean:

```
package json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.resource.spi.IllegalStateException;

import org.leadpony.justify.api.JsonSchema;

@ForEjbDeployment
@ApplicationScoped
public class JsonSchemaValidatorEjb extends JsonSchemaValidatorBase {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("JsonSchemaValidator");

    public JsonSchemaValidatorEjb() {
        //
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            // This is where I can't manage to get a list of the json schema files and process them
            final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            try(
                    final InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream("schemas");
                    final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
                log.info("schema files in directory: ");
                br.lines().forEach(x -> log.info(x));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error trying to parse schema files!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

No Exception is thrown but also no files will be found in the directory provided, e.g. "schemas". The shortened output after EJB started is:

```
[JsonSchemaValidatorService] Started JsonSchemaValidatorService.
[JsonSchemaValidator] schema files in directory: 
[JsonSchemaValidatorService] Loaded schemas in jsonSchemaValidator: {}
```

The file structure of the deployed ear is this:

```
- lib
| - icu4j.jar
| - javax.json-api.jar
| - javax.json.jar
| - json-resources.jar // jar with resources, in this case the schemas
| | - schemas
| | | - person.schema.json
| - json.jar // jar containing @ApplicationScoped beans for war und ejb
| - justify.jar // json schema processing library used
- META-INF
| - maven
| | ...
| - schemas
| | - person.schema.json
| - application.xml
| - MANIFEST.MF
- schemas
| -person.schema.json
- json-ejb3.jar
```

As you can see I have managed to bundle the `schemas` folder and the single json schema file in multiple locations, but none of this works.

Is this even possible to achieve?
Am I wrong with the path specified at `getResourceAsStream("schemas")`?

The goal is to load all existing json schema files at startup to parse them to JsonSchema objects once to validate them later on (it will be a message-driven bean, by the way).

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Class+Loading+in+WildFly? I would start with defining jboss-deployment-structure.xml. As a side note - any explicit reason to use EAR packaging? Almost all features of JavaEE are available with WAR packaging (which is much simpler) starting from JavaEE 6.

Comment: The way to iterate over your schemas is answered in [How to list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file). Given that, there is no reason these resources cannot be in the same jar as your EJBs. They only need to be in a separate jar in the EAR/lib directory if you need to access them from other jars or WARs in the EAR. You do not need to be concerned with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` unless you're doing something funky - which you are not.

Comment: @IllyaKysil No there is no particular reason for an ear, a co-worker also told me so and I have managed to package my EJB into the war, thanks! Still no success in reading the folder though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a nice solution that works both in Servlet and EJB context and eliminates the need for distinguishing between them.

Since I am not able to list the files inside the schemas folder from within an EJB but access and read single files I came up with the idea to use an auto-generated – at build time – file containing the list of all JSON schema files and using this to process the schemas

#### Moving EJB to WAR deployment

First I followed the advice from @IllyaKysil and moved my EJB from an EAR deployment to the already existing and working WAR deployment

#### Move schema files into JAR

The original approach had the JSON schema files in both WAR and EAR deployments. I now have the files inside `src/main/resources/schemas` folder of the JAR project which I have a maven dependency on in the WAR project. Result structure of archive is:

```
| jee7-test.war
| - WEB-INF
| | - lib
| | | - json-validator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
| | | | - schemas
| | | | | - person.schema.json
| | | | | - schemaList.txt
```

#### Generate schemaList.txt at build

Using the maven antrun plugin a file is created in `src/main/resources/schemas` with each file in the schemas directory with an extension of `.schema.json` on a seperate line:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <configuration>
            <target>
               <fileset id="schemaFiles"
                  dir="src/main/resources/schemas/" includes="*.schema.json" />
               <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}"
                  property="schemaFileList" refid="schemaFiles">
                  <map from="${basedir}\src\main\resources\schemas\" to="" />
               </pathconvert>
               <echo
               file="${basedir}\src\main\resources\schemas\schemaList.txt">${schemaFileList}</echo>
            </target>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Content of generated file then is:

```
person.schema.json
```

#### Reading schemaList.txt and parsing schemas

Final step is reading the file with the list of JSON schema files and process each line to parse the corresponding schema file:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JsonSchemaValidator implements IJsonSchemaValidator {

    protected JsonValidationService jvs = JsonValidationService.newInstance();
    protected ConcurrentHashMap<String, JsonSchema> schemaMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JsonSchema>();
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger("JsonSchemaValidator");

    public JsonSchemaValidator() {
        //
    }

    private String SCHEMA_FOLDER = "schemas/";
    private String SCHEMA_LIST_FILE = "schemaList.txt";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            // load file containing list of JSON schema files
            try (final InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FOLDER + SCHEMA_LIST_FILE);
                    final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
                // each line is a name of a JSON schema file that has to be processed
                br.lines().forEach(line -> readSchema(line, loader));
            }
            log.info("Number of JsonSchema objects in schemaMap: " + schemaMap.size());
            log.info("Keys in schemaMap: ");
            schemaMap.forEachKey(1L, key -> log.info(key));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error trying to parse schema files!", e);
        }
    }

    private void readSchema(String schemaFileName, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        // only use part of the file name to first dot, which leaves me with "person"
        // for "person.schema.json" file name
        String schemaName = schemaFileName.substring(0, schemaFileName.indexOf("."));
        JsonSchema js = jvs.readSchema(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FOLDER + schemaFileName));
        // put JsonSchema object in map with schema name as key
        schemaMap.put(schemaName, js);
        log.info("Schema " + schemaName + " added: " + js.toJson());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Problem> validate(String json, String schemaName) {
        List<Problem> result = new ArrayList<Problem>();
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = schemaMap.get(schemaName);
        JsonReader reader = jvs.createReader(new StringReader(json), jsonSchema, ProblemHandler.collectingTo(result));
        reader.read();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, JsonSchema> getLoadedSchemas() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(schemaMap);
    }
}
```

#### Result

JSON strings from input can now be validated against a JSON schema without the need to parse the schema over and over again

```
@Inject
IJsonSchemaValidator jsv;
...
List<Problem> problems = jsv.validate(inputJson, "person");
```

Logged output after JsonSchemaValidator instance has been created:

```
Schema person added: {"$id":"....}
Number of JsonSchema objects in schemaMap: 1
Keys in schemaMap: 
person
```

Comment: Your way may be the most portable. I just tried to implement it myself and the deployment gives me a root URI of `vfs:/content/list-resources.war/WEB-INF/classes` which is a reference to the WildFly virtual file system.

Answer (score 0):

The way to iterate over your schemas is answered in [How to list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file).

Given that, there is no reason these resources cannot be in the same jar as your EJBs. They only need to be in a separate jar in the EAR/lib directory if you need to access them from other jars or WARs in the EAR.

You do not need to be concerned with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` unless you're doing something funky - which you are not.

Also, you cannot read resources from inside the EAR itself, such as your `ear/META-INF/schemas`. This counts as funky and you will still need the solution indicated above to iterate.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the hint, but the linked solution isn't working. I do get a `ZipInputStream` reference to my jar, but the first call to `ZipEntry e = zip.getNextEntry();` leads to entering the branch `if (e == null) break;` and nothing is found.