# Find filenames in a folder inside nested JARs

Tags: java, java-8

I'm having trouble reaching a target folder "images" when my application is packaged as a JAR.
I am not after getting a single file, what I want is a list of all the .jpg files in the "images" folder.

I've tried this:
`URI uri = getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("images").toURI();`

This returns: `jar:file:/C:/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/images`

Then i tried to create a stream to iterate over the files like this:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFilesSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap());
Path p = fs.getPath("images");
Files.walk(p).forEach(path -> System.out.println(path));
```

This just gives med a FileNotFoundException.

So, how can I access the "images" folder inside my nested JARs?

EDIT: This is not duplicate of: [How to list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file). I have tried every thing in there. The difference is that i have a JAR INSIDE another JAR, nested JARs. This is what is creating the issue i believe.

Comment: I wrote an answer but didn't post it in time. You can see it here: https://pastebin.com/bViDmy53

Comment: @lino-says-reinstate-monica Can you please remov the duplicate tag as this is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to JDK 12, there is no support for nested jar files in the builtin `ZipFileSystem` at all.

E.g., the `newFileSystem` method of `ZipFileSystemProvider` accepting a `Path` has a statement like

```
if (path.getFileSystem() != FileSystems.getDefault()) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Even for JDK 12, getting hands on nested zip filesystems is not easy due to a consistent mistreatment of `jar:` URLs.

The syntax for `jar:` URLs [has been specified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) as:

```
jar:<url>!/{entry}
```

which implies that the correct URL for your resource would be

```
outer file                file:/C:/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
nested jar file       jar:file:/C:/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
entry of nested   jar:jar:file:/C:/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/images
```

To parse such a URL, you would have to extract the location of the jar file using the part between the first `jar:` and the last `!/` and recursively parse that.
However, all JDK code I’ve seen, regardless of backing the `URL` API or the `FileSystem` API consistently fails to do so, using `indexOf("!/")` rather then `lastIndexOf("!/")`.
So nested `jar:` URIs/URLs simply don’t work.

The only way to get hands on a nested file system is to open them using `Path` instances already associated with a `FileSystem`:

```
Path outer = Paths.get("C:", "test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
ClassLoader cl = null;
try(FileSystem outerFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(outer, cl);
    FileSystem innerFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(
        outerFs.getPath("/BOOT-INF/lib/core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"), cl) ) {

    Path p = innerFs.getPath("images");
    Files.walk(p).forEach(path -> System.out.println(path));
}
```

This works with JDK12 or newer.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've tried your last suggestion here on JDK 8, just throws a `ProviderNotFoundException` there:(.
Made a workaround by listing the names of the files i need in a txt file instead. Its not pretty but it works

Comment: Well yes, `FileSystems.newFileSystem` will iterate over the installed providers, probe them and catch `UnsupportedOperationException`, continuing the iteration, to eventually say that no matching provider has been found. You could iterate over the providers manually, to find the right one and request it to create a new file system instead; that’s how I discovered that it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`…