# How to get the file location of a jar inside of a jar

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classpath

I'm trying to get the file location of a jar inside a jar. This is the code I have that gets the location of the jar file, then I direct it to my Lib folder, and according to my code, the file location does not exit.

```
    private File getThisJar() {
         return new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    }
    
    public void handle() {
         File jar = new File(getThisJar() + "/lib", "JDA.jar");
         if (!jar.exists())
             return;
    }
```

In this the .exists method returns false and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A jar is a file; the entries in a jar are NOT files and cannot be accessed using `File` because `File` only accesses files. If you extract the sub-jar from the outer jar to an actual file, you can then access that file using `File` because it's a file. Otherwise you may want to access the entry in the outer jar, but if so you can't use `File`. _Since_ the outer jar is in the classpath you can access the _data_ of an entry using `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Dave is right! Another possible solution: you can unzip the jar programmatically and then check the existence of the other jar!

Comment: How would I do that Onur? I'm using the File to get an instance of a JarFile, and the JarFile constructor parameter takes a file.

Comment: `JarFile` simply does not support a jar inside a jar. You can use `getResourceAsStream` to get a stream and wrap it in a `JarInputStream`, if processing the contained entries linearly is feasible. The only other option is the filesystem API, [but you need to know the obstacles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980655/2711488).